# MPDF unexpected bold text

Tags: php, mpdf

Here is a code snippet I used to generate PDF when I used mPDF, version of the mPDF is v8.0.

Updated: 30/03/2022, added the settings of mPDF and the stylesheet I used. Found out the "overflow:hidden" in CSS settings triggered the problem.

But a question is, if I do not set the "overflow:hidden" on tables and sometimes when the text inside of the table is pretty long, and font-size will become smaller to make the table fit in a page.

```
$config = [
    'mode' => 'c',
    'format' => "A4",
    'default_font' => 'arial',
    'orientation' => "P",
];


$htmlContent = '<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @page {
      margin-left: 12.7mm;
      margin-right: 12.7mm;
      margin-top: 20mm;
      margin-bottom: 20mm;
      margin-header: 5mm;
      margin-footer: 5mm; /* <any of the usual CSS values for margins> */
      marks: none;
    }

    table{
      width:100%;
      overflow:hidden;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page_holder">
        <p>25/03/2022</p>
        <p>Dear Dr Jayden,</p>
        <p>Thank you for agreeing to undertake respirable crystalline silica health monitoring for the following worker.</p>
        <table class="wp-block-advgb-table advgb-table-frontend is-style-padding ">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Jayden
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff"><strong>Date of Birth</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">31/12/1989
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff"><strong>Description of tasks this worker will complete with engineered stone
                        fabrication</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Final Task
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff"><strong>History working with engineered stone</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">History
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <p><strong>If yes, please list previous work history with engineered stone:</strong></p>

        <table class="wp-block-advgb-table advgb-table-frontend is-style-padding " style="table-layout: fixed">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Workers Name</td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Jayden
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Date of Birth</td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">31/12/1989
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Description of tasks this worker will complete with engineered stone
                    fabrication</td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">Final Task
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff"><strong>History working with engineered stone</strong></td>
                <td style="background-color:#f4f4f4;border-width:2px;border-top-color:#ffffff;border-right-color:#ffffff;border-bottom-color:#ffffff;border-left-color:#ffffff"
                    data-border-color="#ffffff">History
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <p>I confirm that the minimum health monitoring required has been identified in the attached document; WHSQ Health
            monitoring standard - crystalline silica. Upon completion of the health monitoring could you please provide a report
            for this worker that at a minimum contains the information outlined below.<br>Within the assessment, my business
            requires a level of health monitoring that includes:</p>


        <ul>
            <li>Demographic, medical and occupational history</li>
            <li>Records of personal exposure</li>
            <li>Standardised respiratory questionnaire</li>
            <li>Standardised respiratory function test, including FEV1, FVC, FEV1/FVC - it is strongly recommended this testing
                be undertaken by an accredited respiratory function laboratory and include testing of diffusing capacity.
            </li>
            <li>Chest X-ray full-size PA view - it is strongly recommended an ILO X-ray be undertaken to allow for reading by a
                B-reader.
            </li>
        </ul>


        <p>Please include a confirmation in your report that all requirements of the standard have been met.</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>';

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmlContent);
$mpdf->Output();
```

[image]

Don't know what happens on unexpected bold text after the second table.

I have a bunch of attempt editing the html. I could replicate the problem that when I put piece of bold text between two tables. Could anyone help with if the bold text exists between two tables and keep the normal text after the second table?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. I suspect this is caused by a CSS stylesheet you didn't share. Or, but unlikely, by a mPDF setting you didn't share.

Comment: @Finwe I've updated the code sample and put the CSS and the mPDF settings, after trail and error I found it is caused by "overflow:hidden". If I set the text "If yes, please list previous work history with engineered stone:" from bold to normal, the unexpected bold text below will become normal as well.

Comment: Interestinly, this seems to be caused by the overflow: hidden table definition. As it serves no purpose, feel free to remove it. You can also file a bug report at mPDF github repository, but I have no confidence this will be addressed in a timely manner.